# Extracting website names from link code cleanup

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a program that takes website links and extracts the website name. Right now, it works perfectly, but it is very much a brute force approach and very ugly in my opinion.

Some of the properties of the links are as follows:
- entirely random
- will all contain https:// and .com
- may not contain www.

Here's a random link that I pulled up while shopping to give an example of what I'm talking about. Just to be 100% clear.

```
https://www.walmart.com/ip/Glencairn-Crystal-Whiskey-Glass-Set-of-2-Hailed-as-The-Official-Whiskey-Glass/183116827

remove 'https://www.'
remove '.com/....827'

result = walmart
```

And here is the code for it all:

```
f = open("Links.txt").read().split("\n")
f.remove('')

results = []

for i in f:
    if 'https://' in i:
        results.append(i[8:])

f = results
results = [f[0]]

for i in f:
    if 'www.' in i:
        results.append(i[4:])

f = results
results = []

for i in f:
    results.append(i[:i.find('.com')])

f = open("Results.txt", 'w')

for i in results:
    f.write(i + "\n")

f.close()
```

I tried cleaning it up with the `re` module, but it was throwing some errors when trying to search using `re.search('www.(.*).com', f)`.

I was thinking about using the `[a:]` through `[:b]` notation in python, but since each link may not have `'www.'` it seemed like it would be a faulty solution.

As I mentioned, this code works perfectly well. It's just such a simple thing that I want to get some practice in computer science and make it look like an elegant-ish solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer by Roland Illig, there is a module for that.

Example:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def get_domain_name(url: str) -> str:
    """Return domain name from URL
    """
    parsed_uri = urlparse(url)
    return parsed_uri.hostname


get_domain_name('https://www.ucl.ac.uk/alumni/services')
```

Result:

```
'www.ucl.ac.uk'
```

NB: this requires a full URL with http/https scheme.

Third-level domain extensions are handled with no problems. This is the prefered approach. The Python philosophy is that there should be one obvious way of accomplishing a given task. It doesn't have to be more complicated.

if you know all domain names will end in .com and want to get rid of it, just add `.replace('.com', '')`.

A regular expression can also get the job done. Something like this will return `walmart`:

```
^https://(?:www\.)?([a-z0-9_\-]+)\.com
```

Assuming that the URL always starts with `https://`, and the domain name ends in .com, with `www.` optional and not included in the **capture group**.

To explain this bit: `(?:www\.)?`
The rightmost question mark means the expression in parentheses is optional. `?:` means: match the expression but do not capture it.

This is not an all-purpose expression, it is adjusted to your circumstances and should be good enough for your needs but that's it.

Let's say you have more complicated cases with subdomains, as an example:

```
url = 'www.subdomain.walmart.com'
```

Once you've got the full domain name, you could do some splitting then extract the relevant portions starting from the right, knowing that .com will be the last element:

```
bits=url.split('.')
print(bits)
['www', 'subdomain', 'walmart', 'com']
print(bits[-2])
walmart
```

I think this is slightly more flexible than working with fixed lengths like you're doing.

As for reading/writing files have a look at **context managers** (using the `with` statement).

Your code is not very long but you would still benefit by keeping the parsing in one dedicated function (possibly two), out of your loop. That would make the whole code easier to read and maintain.

One remark regarding `www.`: at some point you will find that some sites do redirect to `ww1` or `ww2` or stuff like that. Not to mention other types of subdomains. It is not safe to assume that the domain name will always be prefixed with `www.` or nothing.

Comment: This is great information! Thanks a lot! I'll get to work making the changes you guys suggested!

Comment: Regarding the extraction of the "interesting part" from the host name: there's a module for that.

Comment: And how would `replace` know that it should only remove the `.com` at the end, and not in `www.complicated.org`?

Comment: The OP said all his/her URLs would end in .com, so the code is clearly tailored to the situation. But it's not an all-purpose solution. It is 'good enough' and simple enough for the task.

Answer (score 1):

You described the idea very clearly, thanks for the example that you gave.

The code looks only half-baked though.

The most important part in getting the code right is to know all involved concepts and how these are called officially. When you know the correct names, you can search for them, and most probably someone else has already programmed everything you need, you just need to stick the parts together.

The official term for the lines from `Links.txt` is URL or URI. These have a well-known format, and Python provides a module to extract the various parts from URLs. For example, googling for "python split url" directly links to the [Python urllib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html), which provides a few examples with their corresponding code.

The part of the URL that you are interested in is called the `hostname`. For the Walmart URL you gave, this would be `www.walmart.com`.

Finding the "most interesting part" of a hostname is not as trivial as it may seem at first. There are countries in which the "top-level domain" actually consists of two parts, for example the University of London can be found at `london.ac.uk`. Once you know the terms "domain" and "top-level" and "second-level", you can google for it at find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916890/extract-2nd-level-domain-from-domain-python).

To test and improve your code, you should split up the work into several small tasks. One of these tasks is to find the "interesting part of the host name" of a URL. In Python, you define a function for this:

```py
def main_host_name(url: str) -> str:
    ...
```

By giving a name to this function and explicitly declaring the parameter and return type, you give the reader of your code a lot of helpful information. It's also easier to test simple pieces of code like this function, rather than the code that reads a whole file and transforms all the links in it.

The variable names in your code are mostly confusing. The computer does not care how you name the variables, but human readers do. By convention, the variable `f` stands for a file. In your code though, you store a list of lines in it. Therefore a better name for the `f` at the top of the code is `lines`.

Next, you wrote `for i in f`. This is too cryptic. It's much easier if the code reads `for line in lines`.

At the bottom of the code you do something very unusual. You assign a value of a *different type* to the same variable that you already used before. In the upper half of the code, `f` is a list of strings, and in the lowest part of the code, it's a file. That's confusing for human readers.

There is no need that you only use 3 different variable names. You can (almost) choose whatever name you want for the variables. There is absolutely no requirement to have single-letter names. That was common in the 1970s and still is in code from mathematicians or physicists, but that's only because these people are accustomed to abbreviated names.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I actually do come from math/physics, which I suppose would explain my use of single letter variable names. But you are right. I will go spruce them up. I think the hardest part of any problem is beginning to accurately describe it. Thanks for laying things out! It's a great answer!